# Dask dataframe get second highest value and column name

Tags: dask

This code gives me the highest value and column name.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

cols=[0,1,2,3,4]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, len(cols)), columns=cols)
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=4)
ddf['max_col'] = ddf[cols].idxmax(axis=1)
ddf['max_val'] = ddf[cols].max(axis=1)
```

I want to get the second higest as well. Something like:

```
ddf['max2_col'] = ddf[cols].idxmax2(axis=1)
ddf['max2_val'] = ddf[cols].max2(axis=1)
```

Are there functions like `idxmax2` or `max2`? Or any other optimized way for doing this?

Comment: Ad your question is.... ? Please EDIT your post; do not post comments to your own post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should normally try to figure out how to do what you want to do with pandas first. If you cannot, and pose that question instead, with the pandas tag, you will get a faster answer.

The following appears to work for pandas, although it may not be elegant

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

cols=[0,1,2,3,4]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, len(cols)), columns=cols)
def make_cols(df):
    df['max2_col'] = df[cols].values.argsort(axis=1)[:, -2]
    df2 = df[cols].values.copy()
    df2.sort(axis=1)
    df['max2_val'] = df2[:, -2]
    return df
```

so to apply it to the dask variant, you can do

```
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=4)
ddf.map_partitions(make_cols)
ddf.head()
```